# Is there a way in mongoose to not create a collection if not found?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

We are creating a discord bot for task management based on teams. We're using a collection as a team. In code to find a team and add tasks to it we use: `const Team = await mongoose.connection.collection(teamName, {strict: true});` and `strict` is supposed to make it so that the collection isn't created when it's not found but instead this happens:

[image: creating task even though team doesn't exist]

I've tried with no luck as the mongoose has no documentation on the options and everything I've tried doesn't work.

> **How do I make `mongoose.connection.collection(teamName)` return an error if `teamName` isn't a collection name/isn't found?**

Comment: You can check if a collection exists or not in a database, - and do some action (e.g., throw an error) based upon it.

Comment: exactly what I'm trying to achieve, `mongoose.connection.collection(collection name)` is the way to do that but I don't want it to create the collection if it already exists. That method creates the collection if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `strict: true` should do it, but doesn't.
Mongoose doesn't mention the options it accepts, though usually it takes the ones used by the underlying mongo client.
But it does mention in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-collection) that it makes missing collections:

> Retrieves a collection, creating it if not cached.

I looked into the [repo](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L1000), and the `collection` method always makes a missing collection

> ```
> Connection.prototype.collection = function(name, options) {
>  const defaultOptions = {
>    autoIndex: this.config.autoIndex != null ? this.config.autoIndex : >this.base.options.autoIndex,
>    autoCreate: this.config.autoCreate != null ? this.config.autoCreate : >this.base.options.autoCreate
>  };
>  options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options ? utils.clone(options) : {});
>  options.$wasForceClosed = this.$wasForceClosed;
>  if (!(name in this.collections)) {
>    this.collections[name] = new Collection(name, this, options);
>  }
>  return this.collections[name];
> };
> ```

The mongo-client [collection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection) does take a strict parameter.
You can access it from `mongoose.connection.client.db()`

### Update

Here is how you can call it:

```
mongoose.connection.client.db().collection(teamName, {strict: true}, function (error, collection) {
  console.log('error', error);
  console.log('collection', collection);
})
```

### Example

```
>
> mongoose.connection.client.db().collection('nonExistantCollectionName', {strict: true}, function () { console.log(arguments) })
undefined
> [Arguments] {
  '0': MongoError: Collection nonExistantCollectionName does not exist. Currently in strict mode.
      at Function.create (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:57:12)
      at toError (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:130:22)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:482:9
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:704:5
      at handleCallback (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:109:55)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:840:66
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:704:5
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:925:9
      at CommandCursor._endSession (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:397:7)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:923:12
      at maybePromise (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
      at CommandCursor.close (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:916:12)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:840:27
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:739:9
      at handleCallback (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:32:5)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:683:38
      at _setCursorNotifiedImpl (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:696:10)
      at setCursorNotified (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:683:3)
      at done (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:458:16)
      at queryCallback (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:503:20)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:548:9
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:704:5
      at executeCallback (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:65:7)
      at callbackWithRetry (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:112:14)
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/command_v2.js:102:9
      at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:405:18
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
    driver: true
  },
  '1': null
}
```

Comment: alright, I'll try it out! so this is a bug then?

Comment: not a bug, it even says in the documentation that it does this. It just doesn't work the same as the `mongo-client`, which is unusual for the `connection` methods.

Comment: `.client.collection` doesn't seem to exist, I've tried .getClient().collection but collection doesn't exist then.

Comment: @YTGAMEWORKS You are right, I got the syntax wrong. The `collection` method is on the db instance on the client. I updated my example. It throws an error when not called with a callback, but you can wrap it in a promise if you need it async.

Comment: It still creates the collection and doesn't return an error but instead returns the created collection.

Comment: @YTGAMEWORKS I tested it locally and it gave me a good output and didn't make a collection. I'll add sample output to my answer

Comment: works! turns out it was an if preventing the code you gave me from executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if a collection exists or not in a specific database - and then perform actions as needed.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
const opts = { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    dbName: 'test' 
};

(async () => {
    const conn = await mongoose.createConnection(uri, opts);
    let collNames = await conn.db.listCollections().toArray();
    collNames = collNames.map(e => e.name);
    console.log(collNames);
    console.log(collNames.includes('existing_coll'));       // true
    console.log(collNames.includes('non_existing_coll'));   // false
    await conn.close();
})(uri, opts);
```

Comment: Yeah can try that, but I really want to be able to do it with the `mongoose.Connection#collection(teamName)` method, more importantly I want to know why it doesn't work plus it makes it look a bit more neat :D But will use this if I can't figure it out!

Comment: I dont think Mongoose has methods to list and check collection names (or their existence) directly. `db.listCollections().toArray()` is the native MongoDB NodeJS driver API.

Comment: you can do something very similar in mongoose as well.